# Checking if div contains p element with php

Tags: php, html, dom, joomla

I was wondering if it is possible to see if a parent element has a child element with php? I know it is possible with jQuery, but I need to do it with php because I need to make a check that displays my content differently based on the presence of that child element.

What I now have is:

```
<?php if ($showLeftColumn) : ?>
            <aside class="sppb-col-md-3 custom-style-left">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left-top" style="xhtml" />
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left-center" style="xhtml" />
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left-bottom" style="xhtml" />
            </aside>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

This works now, but it still shows when empty because the position is loaded in standard. What I want is that if the position is loaded then it gets into the first if and then does a check if the child element exists in the parent element.

Does anyone know if this is possible by maybe getting the dom structure or a other easier way?

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to do (the code doesn't contain any p and only one if), but if you want to parse the DOM using PHP, try PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Mmh, yes you are right... I am pretty vage in my question, but thanks for the awnser! The if statement checks if the position left-top has to be loaded. I have set it to true so it will be loaded, but when its loaded it loads in a article that contains a p element and I want to check if it contains that p element because sometimes there will be no article but the position has to be alwasy loaded in.

Answer (score 1):

The following should solve your problem.

```
<?php
        $content = '<aside class="sppb-col-md-3 custom-style-left">
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left-top" style="xhtml" />
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left-center" style="xhtml" />
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left-bottom" style="xhtml" />
                        </aside>';
        if (strpos($content, '<p') === false) {
          //Don't show content, maybe show something else?
        } else {
          echo $content;
        } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please allow me to reformulate your question. Your approach is first to create a problem (create the empty aside), and then to clean it up (find out if the aside is empty), while you can also avoid the problem all together.

Joomla provides the method [countModules()](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDocumentHTML.html#method_countModules), that allows you to make your code dependent on what is to come. You can then rewrite your code as

```
<?php if (($showLeftColumn) &&
        ($this->countModules("left-top") + 
         $this->coutnModules("left-center") +
         $this->countModules("left-bottom"))): 
?>
        <aside class="sppb-col-md-3 custom-style-left">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left-top" style="xhtml" />
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left-center" style="xhtml" />
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left-bottom" style="xhtml" />
        </aside>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Mmh, this seems to make the whole website not load in anymore? I would assume it would just work?

Comment: In case your website doesn't load anymore, the most probable cause is a syntax error in the PHP code. If you just copy-pasted the code, you also copied my unintentional typo: coutnModules instead of countModules in the second instance. -- Sorry